# Xcode/Swift 4 Static table cells that open pdf files

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, static, cell

I understand the concept of passing data between VCs. I would like to know how to ensure a specific row of section should be referenced to open a particular file and if my use of PDFKit is correct.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to manage table cell selections to open pdf files in a new view controller without having hundreds of segues in my storyboard.
This is a pic of my storyboard:
(https://i.ibb.co/jL7nvhv/Screen-Shot-2019-05-07-at-2-41-42-PM.png)

I have previously used drag and drop segues from cells to view controllers but that is time-consuming and seems to slow down the app. In the example I have provided, I wish to have the selected cells open a pdf file describing that cell in more detail.

There is a segue between the view controllers called "detailSegue".
The 'Transport Detail VC' has a UIView on top of it with a 'PDFView class'.
There is no section or row data in the 'Transport Table VC' as I constructed the table from the storyboard.

```
//Transport VC (where i want PDF's to display):
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class TransportViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "", ofType: "pdf"){
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url:        URL(fileURLWithPath:path)) {
                pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
                pdfView.autoScales = true
                pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
                pdfView.document = pdfDocument
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

```
//Transport Table VC

import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

I have no idea where to start. If I dont figure out an alternative I will go back to the 100 segue method.

Ideally I would like to have each cell open up their own pdf file(stored locally and named accordingly i.e ferari.pdf etc...) and have it displayed on the Transport detail VC.

Comment: get name of the file in table did select method and pass to TransportViewController via preparer segue method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below sample I got name of the file in table did select method and pass it to TransportViewController via prepare for segue method

Please find the dropbox link for code

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2697rzajiu2vmm0/PDFSample.zip?dl=0

Note : Only for Toyota I added the PDF file in project

Comment: Vinodh, words cannot express how indebted I am to you for your above and beyond approach to this. I guess I should have made it more clear initially that I was really only looking for how to call similarly named files, but the project you created easily demonstrates how this is possible. Much thanks and appreciation!

Comment: Maybe you could also look at :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088229/xcode-swift4-how-to-add-images-programmatically-to-cells-of-existing-tableview