# How to add images [programmatically] to cells of existing tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to add images to tableView cells of the same names as the tableView cells. i.e. 'Boeing' cell uses 'Boeing.png' image. Some images are of .jpg format.

I have tried adding an array of images in the same manner as the section and row layout. The pictures have the same names as the cells. I have added comments(#1-4) to where I have tried to make changes. This should be rather simple, but I cannot see what I am missing.

```
import UIKit

class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        let  transportMeans = ["Cars" : ["Ferrari", "Chrysler", "Toyota"], "Trains" : ["Steam", "Diesel", "Electric"], "Planes" : ["AirBus", "Boeing", "Cessna"]]
    // #1 added a line for images to be applied:
        var transportImages =   ["Cars" : ["Ferrari.png", "Chrysler.png","Toyota.png"], "Trains" : ["Steam.png","Diesel.png","Electric.png"], "Planes" : ["AirBus.jpg","Boeing.jpg","Cessna.png"]]
        var selectedFileName = ""

        struct Objects {

            var sectionName : String!
            var sectionObjects : [String]!
    //#2 added a line for images:
            var transportImages : String!
        }

        var objectArray = [Objects]()


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    // #3 added term 'value' to key:

            for (key, value, value) in transportMeans {
                print("\(key) -> \(value) -> \(value)")
    //#4 added a line for 'transportImages' in the append section-------:
                objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value, transportImages: value))
            }


        }
```

The errors I am getting with this code are:

> "Editor placeholder in source file", "'(key: String, value: [String])' is not convertible to '(_, _, _)', tuples have a different number of...", "Definition conflicts with previous ..." 
>   @ line: 
>   ,,,
>   'for (key, value) in transportMeans {'
>   ,,,

Comment: transportImages to some other name like sectionImages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `transportMeans` has type: `[String : [String]]`. So in the for loop you should do something like this:

```
    for (key, value) in transportMeans {
        print("\(key) -> \(value) -> \(value)")
        //#4 added a line for 'transportImages' in the append section-------:
        objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value, transportImages: key))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you donmichael, I have tried to use this suggestion, but to no avail-still no images =(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **never** declare struct members as implicit unwrapped optional. If you need optionals declare them as regular optional (`?`). But in this case declare them as non-optional and name the struct in singular form. If the struct members won't be modified you can even declare them as constant

```
struct Object {
    let sectionName : String
    let sectionObjects : [String]
    let transportImages : String
}

var objectArray = [Object]()
```

You are enumerating a dictionary, not a tuple. There is only one `key` and one `value`. And if the image names match the company names you actually don't need the `transportImages` array.

```
var transportImages =   ["Cars" : ["Ferrari.png", "Chrysler.png","Toyota.png"], "Trains" : ["Steam.png","Diesel.png","Electric.png"], "Planes" : ["AirBus.jpg","Boeing.jpg","Cessna.png"]]
```

Just add the `.png` extension with `map`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for (key, value) in transportMeans {
        objectArray.append(Object(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value, transportImages: value.map{$0 + ".png"}))
    }
```

}

Comment: I have followed suggestions vadian. However, still no images to be seen:   here is a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbsjskubmuva7aq/NewTableViewController.swift?dl=0

Comment: Of course not, my code fixes only the error. Edit your question to describe in detail where the images come from (the contents of `transportImages` are only file names) and how the images are supposed to be displayed.

Comment: vadian, it was only after i commented that i realized where the errors were coming from, it was so cimple I couldn't believe i missed it until i read through your post again! great work and a heartfelt thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you using each image for each PDF then declare as below

```
struct Objects {

    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
    var sectionImages : [String]!

}
```

and assign for cell like belo

```
    cell.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionImages[indexPath.row])
```

since you used same name for struct var and image array you got the error

> Editor placeholder in source file", "'(key: String, value: [String])'
>   is not convertible to '(_, _, _)', tuples have a different number
>   of...", "Definition conflicts with previous ..." @ line: ,,, 'for
>   (key, value) in transportMeans {' ,,,

Comment: as simple as that! Thank you again Vinodh!