# TableView array sections reordering themselves? (programmatic fix?)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I list my array in a specific order-however, when I launch simulator, the section array is out of intended order.

I have tried rearranging the array order but can't pin why Xcode keeps rearranging the sections

[image]

Is there something I am missing? If so, how can I fix?
(desired order is as listed in array: Boats -> Trains -> Planes -> Cars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary is unordered by definition. The order in `viewDidLoad` is undefined. I recommend to create the array of objects directly rather than from a dictionary

```
let  transportMeans : [String: [String]] = ["Boats" : ["Tugboat", "Tanker"], "Trains" : ["Bullet", "Freight", "Commuter"],"Planes" : ["Fighter Jet", "Cargo Jet", "Commercial Jet"], "Cars" : ["Coupe", "Truck", "Mini"]]
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    objectArray = [Objects(sectionName: "Boats", sectionObjects: ["Tugboat", "Tanker"], sectionImages: ["Tugboat", "Tanker"]),
                   Objects(sectionName: "Trains", sectionObjects: ["Bullet", "Freight", "Commuter"], sectionImages: ["Bullet", "Freight", "Commuter"]),
                   Objects(sectionName: "Planes", sectionObjects: ["Fighter Jet", "Cargo Jet", "Commercial Jet"], sectionImages: ["Fighter Jet", "Cargo Jet", "Commercial Jet"]),
                   Objects(sectionName: "Cars", sectionObjects: ["Coupe", "Truck", "Mini"], sectionImages: ["Coupe", "Truck", "Mini"])
    ]
}
```

And – [once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088229/how-to-add-images-programmatically-to-cells-of-existing-tableview/56096345#56096345) – **never** declare struct members as implicit unwrapped optional, remove the exclamation mark

```
var sectionObjects : [String]
```

Note: the `sectionImages` array is redundant. You can get the image from `sectionObjects`, too

Comment: This made my xcode explode... the code as you have explained is no good. placing the object array under the viewDidLoad creates many errors.instead of writing partial code can you tell me which lines are affected by this seemingly rewrite of the simple lines that I had?

Comment: What errors? The code does exactly the same as the repeat loop but in a distinct order. Don't forget the trailing `]`. Just copy&paste the entire `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: After some modifications I think I have it fixed. The one thing that caused the most grief was trying to figure out how the 'sectionImages' was made redundant. I could not figure out how to implement that change while still calling an image for my table cells. The fix was in the end to include 'var sectionImages' in the struct as well. Thanks for the answer Vadian!

Comment: Just delete all occurrences of `sectionImages` and in cellForRow replace the line to create the image  with`cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row])`